# Get a specific value of JSON data

Tags: python, json

I'm getting a JSON data from RESTCONF HTTPS request, using the following code.

```
https_request = 'https://' + host + '/restconf/data/' + operation
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/yang-data+json', 'Accept': 'application/yang-data+json'}
r = requests.get(https_request, auth=(user, password), headers=headers, verify=False)
print r.json()
```

The data I got is:

```
{
    "Cisco-IOS-XE-native:Tunnel": {
        "name": 0,
        "bandwidth": {
            "kilobits": 256
        },
        "ip": {
            "address": {
                "primary": {
                    "address": "10.10.1.1",
                    "mask": "255.255.255.252"
                }
            }
        },
        "load-interval": 30,
        "Cisco-IOS-XE-tunnel:tunnel": {
            "source": "GigabitEthernet1",
            "destination": {
                "ipaddress-or-host": "10.2.1.3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I want my function to return the field's `"bandwidth"` value which is `256`. I tried the following but it did not work.

```
capacity = r.json()['Cisco-IOS-XE-native:Tunnel']['bandwidth']
```

Comment: `r.json()['Cisco-IOS-XE-native:Tunnel']['bandwidth']['kilobits']`?

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say "it did not work"? For example, describe what you expect and what exception it throws will be much more helpful. In your case, you are not retrieving the exact desired key.

Comment: @knh190 I forgot to add `['kilobits']` value. With your answer, it worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
j={
    "Cisco-IOS-XE-native:Tunnel": {
        "name": 0,
        "bandwidth": {
            "kilobits": 256
        },
        "ip": {
            "address": {
                "primary": {
                    "address": "10.10.1.1",
                    "mask": "255.255.255.252"
                }
            }
        },
        "load-interval": 30,
        "Cisco-IOS-XE-tunnel:tunnel": {
            "source": "GigabitEthernet1",
            "destination": {
                "ipaddress-or-host": "10.2.1.3"
            }
        }
    }
}
print(j['Cisco-IOS-XE-native:Tunnel']['bandwidth'])
```

This returns:

```
{'kilobits': 256}
```

For 256:

```
print(j['Cisco-IOS-XE-native:Tunnel']['bandwidth']['kilobits'])
```